# Mailgun api keeps returning a 401

Tags: http, curl, rust, https, reqwest

I need to make a request of this type:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
    -F to=bar@example.com \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!
```

I'm using reqwest's `basic_auth()` method for the authentication and `form()` for the data  but i'm getting a 401 error and i don't actually know what the problem is.

The api key is correct since i'm able to make requests by using the mailgun_sdk crate.

Here's my code:

```
async fn foo(configuration: &Settings) {
    let client=reqwest::Client::new();

    let form=HashMap::from([
        ("from", "sample_email@gmail.com"),
        ("to"  , "sample_email@gmail.com"),
        ("subject", "test"),
        ("text","OK")
    ]);

    let _=client.post("https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/<sandbox>/messages")
        .basic_auth("api",Some(&configuration.email_client.api_key))
        .form(&form)
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap();


    // THIS WORKS!
    // let params= mailgun_sdk::send_message::SendMessageParamList::default()
    //     .add(SendMessageParam::From("sample_email@gmail.com"))
    //     .add(SendMessageParam::To("sample_email@gmail.com"))
    //     .add(SendMessageParam::Text("OK"))
    //     .add(SendMessageParam::Subject("Test"));
    //
    // let _= mailgun_sdk::Client::new(&configuration.email_client.api_key,"<sandbox>")
    //     .send_message(params);
}
```

Comment: can you add your reqwest code?

Comment: done . @drewtato

Comment: It looks like reqwest is the only one using the europe API URL. Was your mailgun domain created in EU or US? https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-intro.html#base-url

Comment: OK, that was the issue. Thank you for the help!